# How to calculate a large combinatorial function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, combinatorics

I would like to find the following simple combinatorial formula in Matlab

```
(nchoosek(n,j) * nchoosek(j,k) * nchoose(n-j,i-k)) / (nchoose(n,i)*nchoose(n,j))
```

but as my parameters are large Matlab return Inf as the result. Is anyone aware of a function or tool which can calculate this formula for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each combinatorial number, say

```
nchoosek(n,j)
```

use the following instead:

```
exp( gammaln(n+1)-gammaln(j+1)-gammaln(n-j+1) )
```

The idea is to work with logarithms to avoid overflow, and take the exponential at the end. This relies on the fact that the logarithm of a factorial can be computed *directly* by means of [`gammaln`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/gammaln.html).

Since your expression involves several terms, it's better to remain in the logarithm domain for as long as possible, and use `exp` only once at the end. For example,

```
nchoosek(n,j) * nchoosek(j,k)
```

would become

```
exp( gammaln(n+1)-gammaln(j+1)-gammaln(n-j+1) ...
   + gammaln(j+1)-gammaln(k+1)-gammaln(j-k+1) )
```

As a side note, in your specific case you can apply some simplifications. For example, `nchoosek(n,j)` appears both in numerator and denominator.